# Fixed Header on Top instead of Above

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a fixed header at the top of the page but for some reason it keeps going on top of the container instead. When I use `margin-bottom` or `margin-top` then it still sticks to the container.

**index.css**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline; 
}
.full-container {
    width:100%;
}
.boxborder {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px black;
    -moz-box-shado:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
.header {
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: fixed;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 1200px;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="full-container header boxborder"></div>
        <div class="container boxborder"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apart the answer of @reinder make sure to use z-index as when I try your code container is always on top of header. Try putting a higher z-index value to .header than the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define `top` and `left` in your css for `.header`

Comment: technically, you don't need left. top:0 will put the header at the top of the page always.

Comment: yeah @fredsbend but still answer is correct. You can also define only `top` but more good is to add both. You can declare one side e.g. `top` and can add margins also `margin:0 10px`

Comment: I agree, I just thought it would be good to add it here, it might help @ThreaT to understand what these properties actually do.

Comment: @AspiringAqib You still do not need margins either if you only declare top, eg width set to 100%, like the op seems to show. However, I see your point, to be sure of fixed placement use all that are necessary. In this case, top:0 left:0 right:0. Then with height property there can only be one result on all browsers no matter how it is calculated.

Comment: @fredsbend I know but i think you haven't seen that `also`.